# Hypothetical would/will in past perspective

Tags: questions, will-would

When writing of past conversations and perspectives, is it correct to use 'will' to reference a possibility that did happen (and might still be relevant), followed by 'would' for a possibility that didn't?

> At that meeting, John said that the company will secure the events, and that we would sign the agreement by the end the year.

In this example, the company later secured the events (at least some of them by the date of the sentence), but the people at the meeting didn't sign the agreement.

Alternatively, is it correct to use 'would' in both?

Comment: No. *Would* is employed in both clauses as a simple past representing John's past declaration employing *will*; "Hypotheticality" did not enter into his utterance.

Comment: No, you can't use *will* instead of *would* in your context to differentiate between things that *did* happen in the past and those that *didn't*. You can only use it to identify things that *haven't yet happened* at time of reporting (but which probably *will*, in the fullness of time).

Answer (score 1):

The example is *reported (indirect) speech*. In order to better understand why "will" cannot be used, let's start with:

At the meeting, John said: "The company will secure the events, and we will sign the agreement by the end the year." - *Direct speech*

At the meeting, John said that we would secure the events, and (that) we would sign the agreement by the end of the year. - *Reported speech*

Note: The question of whether something actually happened or not is irrelevant, the reason being, while talking about what happened or what was said, the focus is only upon *reporting* it, exactly in the same tense as it happened.

Answer (score -1):

It should be "would" in both instances because you need the past subjunctive tense.

Comment: Why? Isn't the "subjunctive" basically obsolete now?

Comment: @curiousdannii No, it isn’t, although this answer is wrong for other reasons than that. It’s a simple matter of backshifting.

Comment: @tchrist I'm just hating on the subjunctive ;) English may have a subjunctive *construction* but it doesn't have a *tense/mood*.