# Using "will" to describe (one's ideas about?) the past

Tags: grammar, past-tense, will-would, will-future, future-in-past

Is this dialogue idiomatic:

- I played football at school.
- You [will be/will have been] quite athletic when you met Alice then.

Can you think of other examples?

Comment: It's basically the same as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260087/hypothetical-would-will-in-past-perspective), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2417/narrative-tenses-for-things-that-havent-happened-yet), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540477/a-question-about-past-conditional-clauses), etc. Search for will and would.

Comment: @StuartF  What about
"John entered college. He studies hard for a few years. He will not, however, get a job at the bank as he hopes to. After the graduation, John made a career in politics".

Comment: That sounds wrong. You can't keep changing tenses in a narrative.

Comment: you can use the narrative present: "John enters college. He studies hard for a few years. He does not get a job at the bank. Instead, after graduation he makes a career in politics."

Comment: In the example in the question, "would have been" is the proper tense.

Comment: "You will have been quite athletic" = "I suppose you were quite athletic". In your 'John' example, there is no supposition, just a statement of what happened.